# How to persist data in android, without using SQLite

Tags: android, persistence

I want to persist data , without using SQLite databse. what can i do  for this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or files in device memory or external storage (SD card). References: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 7):

The mainly used data storage methods in android are sqlit,shared preference and using assets or resources.if u dont want to use the sqlite.better try out sharedpreference.but i think u cant handle huge datas using sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize datastructures to a file or write JSON or XML files to a permanent storage(e.g. private storage dir or sdcard).

However you should take into account that Serialization is slow on android. Look also here: [Recommendations for persisting data on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023664/recommendations-for-persisting-data-on-android)

If your data will not consume too much storage you should stay with private storage because SD Cards are not necessarily available to write.